# HOw to make a join in MySQL where the key is a substring of the key2?

Tags: mysql, join

I have to tables, which I want to join (later an left outer join)
in the field refs.isbn are more isbns but also the right one. in the field pdfrefs.isbn is only one right one isbn. So: pdfrefs.isbn is a substring of refs.isbn. Can anyone here help to find my mistake?

Thanks
Walter

I tried following:

```
SELECT
    dfrefs.title,
    pdfrefs.isbn,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(refs.isbn,pdfrefs.isbn),
    refs.url,
    refs.isbn,
    pdfrefs.link_to_pdf
FROM refs
    JOIN pdfrefs
WHERE
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(refs.isbn,pdfrefs.isbn) = pdfrefs.isbn;
```

But the result is not that I would like to expect. Number of Records in pdfrefs is 830 and in refs is 918. I get more then 2000 records in the result. The right join might be less than 918 records.

Comment: I found my mistake: I had some records with empty/blank pdfrefs.isbn. WHen I exclude these `(where pdfrefs.isbn <> '' )`then I get 813 records in the result set.

Comment: The correct way would probably to normalize the field though. That way you could use an actual JOIN instead of a Cartesian product that you filter. You probably should have a look at the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) for the syntax. It would be cleaner to actually use `LEFT JOIN tbl ON expr` instead of this mix. Right now it's an inner join. Performance wise this operation is probably going to be pretty horrible.

Comment: @Seth Thanks a lot, I do improve. Now I see something clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If refs.isbn is substr of pdfrefs.isbn you could use a simple like for join

```
SELECT
    dfrefs.title,
    pdfrefs.isbn,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(refs.isbn,pdfrefs.isbn),
    refs.url,
    refs.isbn,
    pdfrefs.link_to_pdf
FROM refs
JOIN pdfrefs ON  pdfrefs.isbn like concat('%',refs.isbn, '%');
```