# how to join 2 dataframes when the key in DF1 is a substring of the key in DF2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hi I need to join 2 dataframes but they dont have a common column.

instead, I need to do it based on partial/substring match, i.e. I want rows to be associated if the key in DF1 is a substring of the key in DF2.

thanks in advance!

EDIT:

it'd be the pandas variant to this question

[HOw to make a join in MySQL where the key is a substring of the key2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680265/how-to-make-a-join-in-mysql-where-the-key-is-a-substring-of-the-key2)

Comment: Please provide a minimum complete verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, in terms of code?

Comment: Also, once you have provided [mcve], please explain what type of join you require (inner / outer?), (left / right?)..

Comment: yes, my bad, newbie here at SO and I couldn't format the code nicely so I left it out. 
anyways will fix the question and include the answer I found asap.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-create a substring with the partial match on DF2

i.e.

```
DF2['subkey'] = DF2['key'].str[:5] # equivalent to left 6 characters
```

Or, if it is located in various parts of the string itself:

```
DF2['subkey'] = DF2['key'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item in DF1['key'].tolist()])
```

Comment: @vncs please share the answer you found, as I would like to understand why the answer above is **not** satisfactory.